# Не пойму как работает void в c++

Tags: c++

Не пойму как работает `void` в с++. Где-то читал, что если перед функцией ничего не стоит, то подразумевается что там стоит `void`. Но если я его убираю, то вываливается целая куча ошибок.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void line() , msg();
int main()
{
    cout << "HW" << endl;
    line();
    msg();
    return 0;
}

void line(){cout << "line" << endl;}
void msg(){cout << "msg" << endl;}
```

Comment: Кто может или если так правильно скиньте тот код сюда просто я не нашел как форматированно его сюда закинуть, поэтому скинул на pastebin

Comment: Вводите ` ` ` (без пробелов, здесь поставил пробелы, чтобы Вам было видно эти символы), потом сразу на той же строке без пробела метку языка из списка отсюда https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109, потом с новой строки Ваш код и после кода на новой строке ещё раз ` ` `.

Comment: Отвечая на Ваш вопрос, в С++ ничего не подразумевается (по крайней мере в данном случае), всё указывается явно. Если нужен `void`, пишите `void`.

Comment: http://progopedia.ru/typing/strong/

Answer (score 6):

C++ требует явного указания типов. Правило неявного `int` (но не `void`) есть в C.

В принципе компилятор сразу так и пишет при попытке убрать тип:

> ```
> error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
> ```

Поэтому просто указывайте тип там, где требует язык.

А вот в C, например, следующая программа [успешно компилируется](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JlvBVLqOiFA6Up8n), хоть и с ворохом предупреждений:

```
line() , msg();
int main()
{
    line();
    msg();
}

line(){}
msg(){}
```

> ```
> warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int] line() , msg();
> warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int] line() , msg();
> warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int] line(){}
> warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type] line(){}
> warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int] msg(){}
> warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
> ```

Дополнительно замечу, что обычно рекомендуется не объединять несколько объявлений на одной строке с общим типом. Т.е. вместо

```
void line(), msg();
```

лучше для наглядности написать

```
void line();
void msg();
```